# Difference between SQL and excel regarding duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates, ssms, union

So, this is related to the question below. I found a new way to accomplish a merging of data sets. In SQL, I imported the 8 data sets (fixed width text files) individually and then merged them using union. It is my understanding that union removes the duplicates. I used the code given below to do this.

When I used UNION ALL, i get 6755 records. UNION returns 6669. So that tells me that sql removed 86 duplicates. Just as a double check, I import the text files into excel one by one and then combine them. From there, I concatenate across the primary key fields (of which there are 9) and then remove duplicates. Excel removes 107. Can anyone think of a reason as to why I would get differing results when I try to remove duplicates.

```
    SELECT x.* 
    INTO [industrytempa]
    FROM (SELECT * FROM industry21
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry31
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry41
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry51
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry24
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry34
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry44
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM industry54
    ) x
```

Comment: As far as I understand UNION it removes duplicate lines so if you concatenate only the 9 keys you might be identifying some lines as duplicate which are actually not.

Comment: @Pavel_V, is it possible that SQL is removing only rows that are duplicates when the record (22 columns) is viewed as a whole where excel is removing based on duplication on the first 9. The primary key is a composite made up of 9 fields.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thgought. Check the excels - if I am correct then when you concatenate all columns you should get the same number of duplicates

Comment: @Pavel_V, well our intuition did not prove to be correct. When I concatenate across all 22 fields and remove duplicates in excel, it removes the same 107 records.

Comment: Interesting. I would probably suggest extracting the duplicate lines and comparing them. In excel you can simply use COUNTIF, in sql probably using COUNT(*) on grouped UNION ALL select. There probably is easier way but this is all I can think of now.